# Difference between inner ou outer function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm building a front application with reactjs and material-ui. I have Form that call Field components.
To have more beautiful forms i use Tabs. So i follow the material-ui doc that use TabPanel function to wrap tab content. But i made a mistake, i put function inside my component Test

```
export default function Test(props) {
    function TabPanel(props) {
      const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

      return value === index && <Box p={3}>{children}</Box>;
    }   
}
```

Instead of doing this :

```
function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return value === index && <Box p={3}>{children}</Box>;
}

export default function Test(props) {
}
```

With the first version, i lost my focus on my input field after each change. On the second version everything was ok.

Could you tell me why it's different.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first scenario is as this:

Because you have declared your `TabPanel` renderer function with the keyword `function`, it won't be bound to the scope of your functional component `Test`, in order to do this, you'll have to do a lot more job -if you chose the purest JS way-, bounding a function to it's **Direct Parent Scope(Test)** makes it **statically preserve the first copy of it(TabPanel)** during the life time of the parent.

In other words, bounding your `TabPanel` function to the local scope of the `Test` function will preserve the same copy of the `TabPanel` function.

While, if it's not bound, a new function `TabPanel` will be created and used each time a render happens in the `Test` component, thus, it'll entirely re-render your input element and then lose it's `focus`.

to make the first scenario work you can use the ES6 Arrow Function, as this:

```
export default function Test(props) {
    const TabPanel = (props) => {
      const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

      return value === index && <Box p={3}>{children}</Box>;
    }   
}
```

Why would that work? but not the `function` keyword way? because ES6 Arrow Functions Auto bind them self to their Lexical Scope -The scope when they where created(Test() Scope)-, remember, they do it automatically, there is a bunch of stuff that happen under the hood in order for that to happen..

While the second way works just fine because JS will keep a copy of your function in the global scope, in our case `window` is the global scope, it'll be something like `window.TabPanel`, and it'll be preserved the first time JS goes into this file, so, extracting it out of the `Test` function into the global scope will protect it from re-creating itself over and over again whenever a re-render occurs..

I hope I was able to deliver the idea..

If you are willing to understand how binding happens, you'll need to go through the prototype nature of JS.